# Grails with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, grails

Need a direction.

Which approach is better when building Grails with AngularJS app.

1. Use the assests folder for the client code ( ng and JS)
2. Have a seperate folder for client and server ( but a single war file ), like below

https://github.com/hantsy/angularjs-grails-sample

Basically what are the advantages of one over the other.

Thanks is advance

Comment: Current question is too broad and seeking an answer that will most likely be opinion based. Consider reforming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is too broad a question to answer. As a whole, the answer will be: "**It depends..**"

- It depends how you want the apps to be?
- It depends if you want to maintain client and server side implementation in different apps?
- It depends if you want fine grained access to each sector by different teams, avoiding conflicts while development?

I personally don't believe there is any advantage of one over another approach if all you get is one web application. However, the example you are referring to does not have the client and server implementation in one war.

Client implementation is a [Node.js app](https://github.com/hantsy/angularjs-grails-sample/blob/master/client/scripts/web-server.js) which hosts the Angular component. Angular makes [REST calls to Node web server](https://github.com/hantsy/angularjs-grails-sample/blob/master/client%2Fapp%2Fjs%2Fservices.js) which in turn makes corresponding REST call to the [Grails app](https://github.com/hantsy/angularjs-grails-sample/blob/master/server%2Fgrails-app%2Fconf%2FUrlMappings.groovy).

Alternatively, this can be achieved by hosting the angular component inside `assets` (according to point 1 in the question) in Grails app itself. Static assets (ng/js/css/html) will be served from here (with the help of asset-pipeline plugin), thus removing the need of the Node.js app as stated earlier.

Once again, which approach supersedes other is a broader discussion and differs from person to person.

However, if you have not kept track of recent developments in latest version of Grails then there is a newly available [Grails profile for Angular](https://github.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/tree/master/profiles/angular). On the other hand, Node, Express, Angular (v2 recently) has been a hot cake as well as far as Client side is concerned.

So it would be wise to do more research on this and decide which fits best to the team and ultimately to the organization.

Comment: "dmahapatro":  thanks for the detail explanation. I did have one other question if we use the asset pipeline will we be able to use gulp for minification of the js/html/css files.

Comment: just checked the asset pipeline documentation and it supports the above.